# Modeless dialog created by modal dialog in Compact Framework

Tags: compact-framework, nested-forms

I am working on a Compact Framework application. This particular hardware implementation has a touchscreen, but its Soft Input Panel has buttons that are simply too small to be useful. There are more than one form where typed input is required, so I created a form with buttons laid out like a keypad. The forms that use this "keypad" form are modal dialogs. When a dialog requiring this "keypad" loads, I load the "keypad" form as modeless:

```
    private void CardInputForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        keypadForm = new KeypadForm();
        keypadForm.Owner = this;
        keypadForm.SetCallback(keyHandler);
        keypadForm.Show();
    }
```

The SetCallback method tells the "keypad" form where to send the keystrokes (as a Delegate).
The problem I'm having is that the modeless "keypad" form does not take input. It is displayed as I expect, but I get a beep when I press any of its buttons, and its caption is grayed-out. It seems like the modal dialog is blocking it.
I've read other posts on this forum that says modal dialogs can create & use modeless dialogs. Can anyone shed light on this situation? Is there a problem with my implementation?

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualizing how you are creating then calling this modeless form. Could you update the question with that code? And, for what you are doing, a Panel control with the buttons should work well.

Comment: Or just writing and installing an actual SIP...

Comment: Yes, @ctacke is saying that it is possible to create your own SIP and install it. We do this because we use a larger 8" screen and want a bigger keyboard. I do not know why your form wouldn't work. what operating system?

Comment: @jpcode2, I am not "calling" the form per se, I am simply displaying it using "Show" as the code shows. When a button is clicked, the delegate passed from the modal dialog gets called to handle it.

Comment: @Alan, this is CF 6.0. Development is with VS2005, C#.Net 2.0. The modeless form is nonresponsive. I am trying to avoid writing a SIP but may have to if this doesn't work.

Comment: @pwrgreg007 what version of windows? Windows CE (Compact) ? Windows Mobile?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: Set the keypad form's Parent property, not its Owner property, to the form instance wanting the keystrokes. The keypad dialog's title bar stays grayed out, but the form is active.

```
    private void CardInputForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // (do other work)
        keypadForm = new KeypadForm();
        keypadForm.Parent = this;
        keypadForm.Top = 190;         // set as appropriate
        keypadForm.Show();
    }
```

Be sure to clean up when done with the parent form. This can be in the parent's Closing or Closed events.

```
    private void CardInputForm_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        // (do other work)
        keypadForm.Close();
        keypadForm.Dispose();
    }
```

There are two panels on the keypad form, one with numerals and one with letters and punctuation that I want. There is also an area not on a panel that is common to both, containing buttons for clear, backspace, enter/OK, and cancel. Each panel has a button to hide itself and unhide its counterpart ('ABC', '123', for example). I have all the buttons for input on the keypadForm fire a common event. All it does is send the button instance to the parent. The parent is responsible for determining what action or keystroke is desired. In my case I named the buttons "btnA", "btnB", "btn0", "btn1", "btnCancel", etc. For keystrokes, the parent form takes the last character of the name to determine what key is desired. This is a bit messy but it works. Any form wishing to use the keypad form inherits from a base class, defining a method for callback.

```
    public partial class TimeClockBase : Form
    {
        public TimeClockBase()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // (other implementation-specific base class functionality)

        public virtual void KeyCallback(Button button)
        {
        }
    }
```

The click event on the keypad form looks like this.

```
    private void btnKey_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // play click sound if supported
        (Parent as TimeClockBase).KeyCallback(sender as Button);
    }
```

The method in the parent form looks like this.

```
    public override void KeyCallback(Button button)
    {
        switch (button.Name)
        {
            case "btnCancel":
                // setting result will cause form to close
                DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
                break;
            case "btnClear":
                txtCardID.Text = string.Empty;
                break;
            // (handle other cases)
        }
    }
```